# Python not creating csv file after parsing - using selenium and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

My code works in two parts

1. Opens browser with selenium and adds in the details to get results from a page
2. Parse the html of the results page and write that to a csv file.

Problem
The second part works only if I download the page and manually add the local url (on my computer). If I add the first part of the code, selenium opens the browser but no csv file is exported.

Things I've used to write this - 
Ubuntu Mate 18.04
Pycharm editor
Firefox Browser

I have printed every level of the code and got the right output. However, output stops after the for loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'/home/pierre/PycharmProjects/scraping/venv'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://karresults.nic.in/indexPUC_2019.asp')

reg = browser.find_element_by_id('reg')
reg.send_keys('738286')

sub = browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn-default')

sub.click()

url = browser.current_url

my_url = url

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

results = []

for record in page_soup.findAll('tr'):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        results = results + [data.text.replace(u'\xa0', u'').strip()]

        print(results)

        with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
            for item in results:
                f.write(item + ',')
```

No errors on Pycharm console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to re-request for updated URL, you have to wait for a couple of seconds using a time module.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'/home/pierre/PycharmProjects/scraping/venv'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://karresults.nic.in/indexPUC_2019.asp')

reg = browser.find_element_by_id('reg')
reg.send_keys('738286')

sub = browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn-default')

sub.click()

time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
results = []
for record in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        results = results + [data.text.replace(u'\xa0', u'').strip()]
        with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
            for item in results:
                f.write(item + ',')
```

csv file O/P:

```
Name,ANIKET ANIL BALEKUNDRI,Reg. No.,738286,ENGLISH,76,,76P,HINDI,76,,76P,Part A - TOTAL,152,PHYSICS,44,30,74P,CHEMISTRY,46,30,76P,MATHEMATICS,73,,73P,BIOLOGY,55,29,84P,Part B - TOTAL,307,GRAND TOTAL MARKS,459,FINAL RESULT,First Class,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your code but the csv file is still not there. I think I've messed up something on my machine. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should create a new workspace and try my code because it's working perfectly on my system. I am using ubuntu18.04 and chrome browser.

Comment: Ran your code directly in the terminal. Worked like a charm! better than Pycharm :) Thanks a lot! Spent a night on this like an idiot.

Comment: @Pierre Carvalho accepts my answer if it's solved your problem.

Comment: you shouldn't use a sleep. use an explicit wait (WebDriverWait) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mr. Goldberg. Is this because it has better error handling and control of waiting for specific elements?